# noncanonical and non-echo mode not working with pipe

Tags: c, linux, terminal, pipe

Recently, I am trying to write a simple version of Linux command `more`.  In order to do that, I need to enter noncanonical mode and non-echo mode in the terminal so that I get the input immediately after keypressing and terminal does not show the character I type.

I did it by doing so:

```
  // set the terminal mode
  struct termios tm;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old);
  tm = old;
  tm.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tm.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
  tm.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSADRAIN, &tm);
```

This works when I use arguments like

```
more test_file
```

But when I tried to pipe `more` with other command like

```
ls /bin | more
```

The terminal is back to canonical and echo mode.  Why does this happen?

Comment: The problem is that when you read from a pipe, it's not connected to a terminal. If you want to be able to read input from both the pipe (through `STDIN_FILENO`) and the terminal, you must open the terminal specifically and configure and read from that descriptor.

Comment: You didn’t test the results of the system calls and they failed, probably with error ENOTTY.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctermid.3.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And how exactly can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, things like `more` are expected to read from `stderr` (or sometimes `/dev/tty` but `stderr` works better). You set terminal on `stdin` instead. That doesn't work so well.

Comment: In the program, I do read keypress from `/dev/tty`.  What should I do?

Comment: In the program, I do read keypress from `/dev/tty`.  What should I do?

Comment: @Rivers Shall: clearly you should also tcgetattr and tcsetattr on your /dev/tty handle then. See the fileno function.